# undefined index invalid argument for loop error

Tags: php

Please point me in the right direction here Im trying to do the following:

1. Multiple select boxes are generated for each eventid
2. User choose who they think will win each event
3. The name of each selectBox is the event id assigned to variable $id
4. At end of while loop I want to extract the array $id value in For loop, however im getting error "undefined offset & invalid argument" on my for loop...

Here is my form

[image]

```
    $i=0;//counter
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $team1 = $row['team1'];
    $team2 = $row['team2'];
    $id[$i]= $row['event_id']; 

    echo'<h3>'.$team1.' VS '.$team2.'</h3>';
    echo'<select name="'.$id[$i].'">';
            echo'<option value="'.$row['team1'].'">'.$team1.'</option>';
            echo'<option value="'.$row['team2'].'">'.$team2.'</option>';
            echo'</select>';    
        $i++;
    }//while
```

Here is my for loop giving error, I suspect problem is in the 
`$_POST['$id']`...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    

    foreach($_POST[$id] as $eventId => $winner){
     echo'<h3>'.$eventId.'</h3>';
}//for loop
}//end isset
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: where id `$id` is defined and how it is initialized?

Comment: @Lashane is this what you are asking $id[$i]= $row['event_id'];  WHERE $row['event_id'];  is retrieved from database

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: What is the exact error message and to what line does it relate?

Comment: I think you need to change $id to just id in your code. You are using a variable when you are actually trying to use a constant.

Comment: no, before `isset` you have to define scalar (not array) variable `$id` - how and where it is defined? note - this variable has nothing to do with $id array which is used in first part of your code

Comment: @ficuscr the message is  Illegal offset type and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Then thinking its as Maximus2012 said then... see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628/php-array-indexing-arrayindex-vs-arrayindex-vs-arrayindex

Comment: @Maximus2012 that works but returns the index of the array and does not give me the event_id im looking for

Comment: @Marilee does the answer from Digits below help ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 its pointing me in the correct directions im playing around with the idea but doesn't quite work

Comment: What part is not working? On a different note, could you use radio buttons in place of dropdown list since your logic needs to choose one of the two options.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I got it working thank you so much for the help, ill change to radiobuttons ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$id is defined as an array here`$id[$i]= $row['event_id'];`. Arrays can not be used as a key in a foreach array or otherwise.
This is what is causing you an error on this line

```
foreach($_POST[$id] as $eventId => $winner){ //$id is an array of values
    echo'<h3>'.$eventId.'</h3>';
}//for loop
```

You have to make a second foreach statement for the $id then use the id values in your current foreach statement.

```
foreach( $id as $key => $val ) {
foreach( $_POST[$val] as $eventId => $winner){
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I tweaked it a bit but it works like a bomb

Answer (score 0):

You don't know what the event_id values are on the action page, so I think you'll have to query for those again something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    /* do your query here */
    $data = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     $data[] = $_POST[$row['event_id']];
    }

    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        print_r($_POST[$value]);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```