# Isset Delete Function for session

Tags: php, session

I have this code that will increment `$_SESSION['count']`, if `$_GET['add']` is clicked.  But when I click `$_GET['remove']` it should be decremented on the user's specific `$_SESSION['cart_(variable)']`;

Here are the variables I have for session cart

[image]

The thing is that I have a lot of cart variables for the future.

This code is for the delete.  I have a problem on deleting specific session variables.  So I have to concatenate the specific id for that row and decrement the value of `$_SESSION['count']`;

Do you have guys any idea of the logic I could use to decremented the session count?

Comment: In the future, post your code as code, not as an image.

Comment: Hello @AmmoPT I really want to post my post it always tell that theres a problem in indentation.

Comment: if(!isset($_SESSION['count'])){ 
        $_SESSION['count'] = 0; 
    } else { 
        if(isset($_GET['add'])) {
            echo ++$_SESSION['count'];
        }
        if(isset($_GET['remove'])) { 
            echo --$_SESSION['count'];
        }
     if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {

          $_SESSION['count'] =$_SESSION['count'] - $_SESSION['cart_/*VAIRABLE*/'];
       
        }

Comment: have a quick read on how to [format code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), you should select the whole code and press the `{}` symbol in the top toolbar.

Comment: I really want to post my code*

Comment: Okay sir @AmmoPT thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [variable as an array key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628/php-array-indexing-arrayindex-vs-arrayindex-vs-arrayindex).

From what I can understand, `$_SESSION['cart_/*CONCATINATING UNIQUE ID*/']` contains an `int` with the amount of times it was added which will be subtracted to `$_SESSION['count']`. In the below code I'm assuming you get the clicked `cart_id` with `$_GET['cart_id']`, you should update it to however you're actually getting it.

Change your code from:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] - $_SESSION['cart_/*CONCATINATING UNIQUE ID*/'];
}
```

To

```
if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $cartkey = 'cart_'.$_GET["cart_id"];
    $_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] - $_SESSION[$cartkey];
}
```

Comment: it worked! Thank you so much. I just changed $_GET["cart_id"] to $_GET["delete"] to make it work. Thank you for your idea. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with below code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["count"]=10;
    if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
        $unique_id = $_GET["id"];
        $key = "cart_".$unique_id;
        if(isset($_SESSION[$key]){
            $_SESSION["count"] = $_SESSION["count"] - 1;
        }
    }
?>
```

Without seeing the full script...I can't understand your problem

Comment: thankyou but it doesnt work for me. But I appreciate it